# Read properties file in android library

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Is it possible that an android library has its own properties file independently from the main app?. I'm writing my android application with Kotlin as well as the libraries.

I've tried to load the properties file in the same directory of my Setting.kt class using the class loader but every time that I executed my code the input stream is not loaded that is the class loader return me a null value. I will be thankful for suggestions.

```
public class Setting {
var file: Properties? = null

init {
    file = Properties()
    try {
        //Option 1
        //val inStream = javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/example/app1/rest/config.properties")
        //Option 2
        //val inStream = javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")
        file?.load(inStream)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //Log.e("SETTING", "Error Load Rest Properties", e)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

fun getEnv(key: String): String {
    return try {
        if (file?.containsKey(key)!!) file?.getProperty(key)!! else key
    } catch (except: ClassCastException) {
        key
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Look into android SharedPreferences.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

These are persistent xml stores which exist alongside the application, independent of your source code. Very useful.